# How to insert a pdf file as an image in HTML?

Tags: html, image, file-upload

`<img src="img.pdf">` doesn't work due to it being a pdf. I don't like the `embed` and `iframe` environments either, since they add the pdf viewer options, the scroll etc. I tried converting the pdf to an image with the `convert` and `pdftoppm` commands on Linux, but these result in the image having extra white space on top and bottom to fit A4 format, and/or makes the background black (instead of white or transparent).

Any ideas?

Comment: *"I don't like the `embed` and `iframe` environments either, since they add the pdf viewer options, the scroll etc."* - Why shouldn't they?  If you're serving a PDF to the user then how (or if) it renders in the browser is entirely up to that user's PDF viewing functionality and their browser.  It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve or what the ultimate goal is here.

Comment: @David My pdf is basically an image, it's just stored as a pdf. Why would I, or anyone else visiting my site, want pdf viewer options and scrolls on an image? It's not clear to me what you don't understand: I just want to display my image, which happens to be a pdf, as an image, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: If you want it to be an image instead of a PDF then it sounds like your data is in the wrong format.  Rather than trying to change the behavior of users' browsers, change the data.  *Automatically* converting PDFs to image formats can certainly result in undesirable outcomes and may need some manual tweaking, depending on the PDF being used.  But ultimately this is an issue upstream from the actual display of the data.  You need a (potentially manual) step before displaying it which converts the data to the format you want.

Comment: @David Hence the converting I've mentioned. To be honest, this seems like an issue with HTML. I don't see why a pdf cannot be simply treated as an image, like it can in say LaTeX with `\includegraphics{img.pdf}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

"Img" is **in effect** an iFrame of an embedded binary object, but it is borderless since it is statically scaled to one non zoomable size. Note the img above this text is framed as https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpw2l.png
Yes there are ways to make it more dynamic [image: https://media.tenor.com/mEXoadZB1QYAAAAi/man-talking.gif] but vanilla binary PNG/JPG/ETC are imbedded, and ***part of the binary HTML viewer*** renders those fixed areas. You can switch them off if you wish, or they don't display if badly served.

So why is PDF not simply treated like an image as per your question?

The answer is simple they are a different type of binary that requires a different html viewing binary extension. One frequent complaint is why use "menus and scrollbars if not needed for a simple file?"

The answer to that is those controls need to be in the extension, for zoom pan etc. So how comes the FireFox viewer above has none?, that's because **as a user I switched them OFF**.